# Create textViews in the center of linarLayout

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have scrollView

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutScroll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>
```

And I want to fill it with array of strings, and I want to have this strings in the center, but for some reason it isn't in the center, but in the left.

```
for (str in arr) {
    val strTextView = TextView(this)
    strTextView.text = str
    strTextView.textSize = 30f
    val params = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
    strTextView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
    linearLayoutScroll.addView(strTextView, params)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by changing your linear layout width `matchParent` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutScroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Happy coding